# Finding out if a function is inside another function R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a main function e.g. "a" that is called inside 4 different functions, e.g. "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4". 
I want to have an if statement checking when function "a" is called inside either  "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4".

```
funct1 <- function(a){
  if(functionNameThatItIsInside == "a2"){
     var1 <- 24243
   }

if(functionNameThatItIsInside == "a1"){
     var1 <- 22525
   }

if(functionNameThatItIsInside == "a1"){
     var1 <- 2525
   }

if(functionNameThatItIsInside == "a1"){
     var1 <- 636364
   }
}
```

or something like this.

Thanks

Comment: Why you have the same statement, with different `var1` values `functionNameThatItIsInside == "a1"` is repeated 3 times

Comment: Why not just hard code it into each of the functions?

Comment: @iod just want to keep it all in one function

Comment: then replace the four functions with one function with an argument that tells them apart, or have `a` have an argument that can be passed from each of the functions, so `a1` will call `a("a1")` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would preface this by saying this is probably not a good design pattern for R code. Requiring a function to be called from a function with a particular name makes it very difficult to use more generally. But technically you can access the call stack to see what the parent function you were called from is.

You could write

```
funct1 <- function(a){
  called_from <- sys.call(-1)
  if (!is.null(called_from)) {
    parentfn <- deparse(called_from[[1]])
  } else {
    stop("not called from within a function")
  }
  if(parentfn == "a1"){
    var1 <- 24243
  } else if(parentfn == "a2"){
    var1 <- 22525
  } else if(parentfn == "a3"){
    var1 <- 2525
  } else if(parentfn == "a4"){
    var1 <- 636364
  } else {
    stop(paste("called from unknown function", parentfn))
  }
  var1
}
```

And we can test it with

```
a1 <- function() {funct1()}
a1()
# [1] 24243

a2 <- function() {funct1()}
a2()
# [1] 22525

xx <- function() {funct1()}
xx()
# Error in funct1() : called from unknown function xx
```

If would be easier to use if you just passed in a parameter to the function

```
funct1 <- function(a){
  if(a == "a1"){
    var1 <- 24243
  } else if(a == "a2"){
    var1 <- 22525
  } else if(a == "a3"){
    var1 <- 2525
  } else if(a == "a4"){
    var1 <- 636364
  } else {
    stop(paste("called with unknown value", a))
  }
  var1
}
```

and called with

```
a1 <- function() {funct1("a1")}
a1()

a2 <- function() {funct1("a2")}
a2()
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `switch`

```
f1 <- function(a) {
        a <- deparse(substitute(a))
         switch(a, 
             "a1" = 24243,
             "a2" = 22525,
              "a3" = 2525,
              "a4" = 636364,
         default = NA)
        }
f1(a1)
#[1] 24243
f1(a2)
#[1] 22525
```

---

Also, with the OP's current implementation, the 'var1' assignment object is not `return`ed

```
...
if(functionNameThatItIsInside == "a1"){
     var1 <- 636364
   }
 var1
 }
```

Comment: that's not what OP asks for. They're asking for a function that determines what function is the function being called from, and reacts accordingly. So if you ran function `a1` and `a` is called from within it, it will react differently than if it's called from within `a2`

Comment: @iod That would be changing the value of `24243`, 22525 etc to function names, It is not clear though from the OP's code

Comment: I want the value of var1 to change depending on the function it is called in

Comment: no it won't. Here's how I understand it: there's a function `a`. If it's called from within the function `a1`, it should return `1` (for example), if it's called from within function `a2`, it should return `2`. I can't see what's the sense in this, instead of creating different functions for within each function, but that's the question.